# Calculate bias and variance in ridge regression MATLAB

Tags: matlab, regression, variance

I can't get my mind around the concept of how to calculate bias and variance from a random set.

I have created the code to generate a random normal set of numbers.

```
% Generate random w, x, and noise from standard Gaussian
w = randn(10,1);
x = randn(600,10);
noise = randn(600,1);
```

and then extract the `y` values

```
y = x*w + noise;
```

After that I split my data into a training (100) and test (500) set

```
% Split data set into a training (100) and a test set (500)
x_train = x([  1:100],:);
x_test  = x([101:600],:);
y_train = y([  1:100],:);
y_test  = y([101:600],:);
train_l = length(y_train);
test_l  = length(y_test);
```

Then I calculated the `w` for a specific value of `lambda` (1.2)

```
lambda = 1.2;

% Calculate the optimal w
A = x_train'*x_train+lambda*train_l*eye(10,10);
B = x_train'*y_train;
w_train = A\B;
```

Finally, I am computing the square error:

```
% Compute the mean squared error on both the training and the 

% test set
sum_train = sum((x_train*w_train - y_train).^2);
MSE_train = sum_train/train_l;

sum_test = sum((x_test*w_train - y_test).^2);
MSE_test = sum_test/test_l;
```

I know that if I create a vector of `lambda` (I have already done that) over some iterations I can plot the average `MSE_train` and `MSE_test` as a function of `lambda`, where then I will be able to verify that large differences between `MSE_test` and `MSE_train` indicate high variance, thus overfit.

But, what I want to do extra, is to calculate the variance and the `bias^2`. 
Taken from [Ridge Regression Notes](http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/764-F11/notes/9-1.pdf) at page 7, it guides us how to calculate the bias and the variance.

My questions is, should I follow its steps on the whole random dataset (600) or on the training set? I think the `bias^2` and the variance should be calculated on the training set. Also, in Theorem 2 (page 7 again) the bias is calculated by the negative product of `lambda`, `W`, and `beta`, the `beta` is my original `w` (`w = randn(10,1)`) am I right?

Sorry for the long post, but I really want to understand how the concept works in practice.

**UPDATE 1:**

Ok, so following the previous paper didn't generate any good results. So, I took the standard form of Ridge Regression Bias-Variance which is:

[image]

Based on that, I created (I used the test set):

```
% Bias and Variance

sum_bias=sum((y_test - mean(x_test*w_train)).^2);
Bias = sum_bias/test_l;

sum_var=sum((mean(x_test*w_train)- x_test*w_train).^2);
Variance = sum_var/test_l;
```

But, after 200 iterations and for 10 different lambdas this is what I get, which is not what I expected.

[image]

Where in fact, I was hoping for something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`sum_bias=sum((y_test - mean(x_test*w_train)).^2); Bias = sum_bias/test_l`

Why have you squared the difference between `y_test` and `y_predicted = x_test*w_train`?
I don't believe your formula for bias is correct. In your question, the 'bias term' above in blue is the `bias^2` however surely your formula is neither the bias nor the `bias^2` since you have only squared the residuals, not the entire bias?